Am I Allowed To Run a USA LLC from Argentina while on a Student Visa?
I’m planning to move to Argentina to study for a bachelor’s degree, but I haven’t arrived yet. While I’m there, I was thinking about running an LLC business that doesn’t have any clients or connections to Argentina at all.
I came across this section in Argentina’s immigration law (Art. 51) that talks about work rights for residents:

ARTICLE 51. — The admitted or authorized foreigners as “permanent
residents” will be able to perform any gainful or profitable job or
activity, as self-employed or as an employee, being protected by the
corresponding law. The admitted or authorized foreigners as “temporary
residents” will be able to perform them only during the term of the
authorized stay.

I think students fall into the temporary resident category, which seems to mean we’re allowed to work during our stay, but I’m not 100% sure about this. Does anyone whether this means that in my case i am legally able to run the business while studying?
Also, is there any limit on how much I’d be allowed to work on my business(if i can work at all) while on a student visa? I’d really appreciate hearing from people with direct experience who’ve studied or worked in Argentina under similar circumstances.
Here’s the link to the law if it helps: Ley de Migraciones 25871, English version.
For your info guys i am from Algeria.
Thanks so much! 

While I have no idea about the visa situation, you will have 3 countries who may be interested in trying to get taxes from you and/or your LLC: your home country (because you're a citizen), the US (because the LLC is registered there) and Argentina (because you live and work there). While there are tax treaties, I'm not sure there are for all combinations here (DZ/US, DZ/AR, US/AR), and they may not have the result you are aiming for. Most likely you will owe taxes in AR. Is there any reason you have an LLC in the US? Do you have any employees in the US?

@jcaron i think usa llc's only tax you in case you are a usa resident and if i leave algeria i will no longer be a tax resident, so i am okay with paying taxes to argentina but i want to know whether i am legally allowed to run the business.
In addition to this the llc serves only as a structure i am the sole owner and have no employees.

@ClioProto I think a US based LLC will be taxed if there is US sourced income through that LLC.  It's not (entirely) based on your residency but the source of your income.  So you may be faced with US taxes also (but this is unlikely to be any different from being based in Algeria)

@jcaron The LLC in the US is a disregarded entity and doesn't affect taxes at all on the federal level, and in most states on the state level

@littleadv i a happy paying taxes, the issue is whether i can run the business while on a student visa or not.
